# MySQL isn't updating data with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was trying to build a simple comment section in my website. I created two fields (or boxes) with Name and Comment. Now if I fill up the Name and Comment fields and hit Submit it shows "Webpage isn't found" error (See the [attachment)](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/100402704740320621129/albums/6051632515227573457/6051632522644933458?pid=6051632522644933458&oid=100402704740320621129). Besides, nothing is updating into my database.

[NOTE: After all my local server is properly installed and everything else works fine. I worked with my phpMyAdmin before and that time it was able to derive data from the database. WAMP server is also running. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS45YAqCgX8&list=FLfd3LPPe6StrSQhv3DufC2w) and code.]

main.php:

```
 <!--php code for comment section starts--> 
 <?php
  require ('connect.inc.php');
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $comment=$_POST['comment'];
  $submit=$_POST['submit'];

  if($submit){
  if($name&&$comment){

  $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(name, comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')"); 
  }else{
  echo "Please fill all the fields";
 }

  }

 ?>
<!--php code for comment section ends--> 


<!--building a comment section starts-->
<form action="main.php method="POST">

<table>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/> </td> </tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"/> </td></tr>

</table>
</form>
<!--building a comment section ends-->
```

connect.inc.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("comment_section");
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: If you have a local server installed, you should access your page through that server, not through the file-system `file:///C:/xampp/....`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a quote in `action="main.php` <=

change it to `action="main.php"`

that's why you're getting a Webpage isn't found error.

---

*Plus*, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s), immediately following your opening `<?php` tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will help signal errors found in code.

and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

---

Sidenote:

*Now,* if that still throws an error of `file not found`, keep in mind that `main.php` is not the same as `Main.php` on certain servers, so make sure the filename is in fact named `main.php` all in lower-case; this is the same as `self`.

You can also use `<form action="" method="POST">` since your entire code is inside the same page. This will set the action as the same page you are executing the code from.

Comment: hey your answer helps. it doesn't show any display error now. the only thing is that it can't add the data into database, which means updating comment and name doesn't work still.

Comment: @JabirALFatah Did you add error reporting to the top of your PHP?

Comment: yes  I did it. Now there is no "webpage not found error". but no data is updated in the database.

Comment: @JabirALFatah Your table is in fact called `comment` and you have 2 columns named `name` and `comment`?

Comment: @JabirALFatah MySQL is installed and running? I've tested this just now with no problems.

Comment: This is how my database looks like: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/100402704740320621129/albums/6051641033634649121/6051641040684243970?pid=6051641040684243970&oid=100402704740320621129

Comment: yes mysql is running fine.

Comment: by the way, is it the right way to add error report code into the file(s): <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("comment_section");
?> I added the error report code both in my main.php and connect.inc.php file in the same way.

Comment: @JabirALFatah Yes, that is how to do it. Try adding `if (!$insert) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }` after your query. Plus, try increasing your column VARCHAR, and setting your `comment` column as VARCHAR(255) also. Or change the name of it, it might be conflicting with the table name.

Comment: @JabirALFatah Also look at the example #1 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php and use that syntax, see if it throws any errors. Complete with variables. `$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: thanks for all you have done for me. Its too late at night in my country. I will be back to you later.

Comment: @JabirALFatah You're welcome. I setup a DB myself and everything worked fine, using your code exactly as shown, therefore am unable to know what the problem is on your end.